# bubble sort algorithm with nested loops performs better than with one loop JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Here are 2 bubble sort algorithms:

**1:**

```
function bubbleSort(array) {

  let i = 0;
  let startVal = array[i];
  let comparingVal = array[i + 1];
  let iterations = array.length;

  while (iterations > 0) {

    if (comparingVal === undefined) {
      i = 0;
      startVal = array[i]
      comparingVal = array[i + 1]
      iterations--;

    } else if (startVal > comparingVal) {
      array[i] = comparingVal;
      array[i + 1] = startVal;
      startVal = array[i + 1];
      comparingVal = array[i + 2];
      i++;

    } else {
      startVal = array[i + 1];
      comparingVal = array[i + 2];
      i++;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

**2:**

```
function bubbleSortTwo(array) {
  const length = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
        //swap
        let temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

when tested in the browser using `performance.now()` Web API `bubbleSortTwo` yielded faster performance time even though there is a nested loop `O(n^2)` whereas `bubbleSort` only has one loop for which I would assume a time complexity of `O(n)`. Why is this? Or am I missing something somewhere? (I am new to ds and algs so excuse my ignorance I am trying to learn)

Comment: The two functions presented have the same time complexity `n^2` as you compare each of `n` items against all `n` items. The performance difference is due to the code path of the second being simpler than the other.

Comment: (@Blindman67 *you compare each of `n` items against all `n` items* um - only if the input is in reverse order. In an ordered array every item is compared to its neighbours, only. Time and again…)

Comment: @greybeard Add a counter to the inner `while` loop. For 100 items it counts 100 * 100 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

There are *four* instances of

```
    startVal = array[i + c]
    comparingVal = array[i + 1 + c]
```

in **1** (for c 0 or 1).
Don't Repeat Yourself:

```
/**
 * Sort array in-place.
 * @return array
 */
function bubbleSort(array) {

  let iterations = array.length, i = 0;
  let startVal, comparingVal;

  while (iterations > 0) {
    startVal = array[i];
    comparingVal = array[i + 1];
    if (comparingVal === undefined) {
      i = 0;
      iterations--;
    } else {
      if (startVal > comparingVal) {
        array[i] = comparingVal;
        array[i + 1] = startVal;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Generally, the assumption that every loop nesting level adds a factor of n is not valid.
There is reason to it where each loop is iterated cn times for some constant c… which is not the case in **1**: `i` gets reset to 0 `iterations` times.

(dropping the redundant assignment to `startVal` from

```
      array[i + 1] = startVal;
      startVal = array[i + 1];
```

leads to another interpretation of bubblesort:
Where the next value is smaller, "take out" the bigger one.
Keep moving values down while smaller.
Put the value once bigger back in.
)